# sed - How to ignore many special characters together in a string

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I have many shell commands in a large shell script. I want to comment many of them. For eg

```
exec_cmd "mkdir -p $dockerHome/devicemapper/devicemapper"
```

I am able to replace this command with :

```
sed -i -e "s/exec_cmd \"mkdir \-p \$dockerHome\/devicemapper\/devicemapper\"/\#exec_cmd \"mkdir \-p \$dockerHome\/devicemapper\/devicemapper\"/g" check
```

Now, there are quite a few commands like this in a file. Is there a way to write a sed command which ignores all the special characters at once since otherwise the alternative seems to be putting a backslash in front of all special characters in the strings to be replaced.

Comment: Do you really have the above in the file? e.g. `exec_cmd “mkdir` ?

Comment: ...because if yes, your `sed` command `s/exec_cmd \"mkdir...`will not work...

Comment: ... here is a difference between the `LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` as (`U+201C`) and `QUOTATION MARK` as (`U+0022`).

Comment: Do you really want to replace whole lines with no wildcards?

Comment: @choroba - yes, I basically want to comment many lines in a shell script, so I was thinking I can replace the string with a '#' concatenated at the beginning! I have updated the question to clarify it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue.

Its [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) function quotes all the metacharacters for you.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl -pl
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, split /\n/, << '__LIST__';
exec_cmd "mkdir -p $dockerHome/devicemapper/devicemapper"
another command to be commented
__LIST__

    $regex = qr/^($regex)$/;
}

s/$regex/$1 ? "# $1" : $_/e
```

Just fill in the script lines to comment before the `__LIST__`. Save to a file, run as

```
perl script.pl input-file > output-file
```

To edit the input file directly, you can use the `-i` option.